# Extract data from filemaker pro 9 database to oracle database

Tags: oracle11g, odbc, filemaker, heterogeneous-services

Hi can someone suggest and explain a way to extract data from Filemaker Pro 9 to my oracle database, i was reading about odbc driver client but, appear that is only to File Maker extract data from oracle.

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

How big a data set are you trying to move? Would the usual Export techniques in FileMaker Pro work for you? http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6167/~/exporting-data-from-filemaker-pro